# Table TD with colspan in chrome (webkit) not rendering correctly

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-table, webkit, markup

I'm experiencing a webkit rendering issue when attempting use a

```
    <td colspan=5>
```

The majority of the table is set up like this

```
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
```

However, when I add a row with the one td with colspan=5, the td is indented one column to the right. It basically looks like this even though this is not the markup.

```
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
```

Has anyone experienced this indenting and is there any way to correct this?  It renders just fine in IE and Firefox. This seems like it should be basic table functionality.  There are no styles affecting the table

Comment: I left out an important detail.  I am hiding the TR with the td colspan 5  until the user clicks on a link.  Clicking on the link exposes the indented td.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same mark-up in chrome and it seems to render correctly. Could you please check if there are any unclosed  or  tags.